# Autohotkey execute scripts

Tags: if-statement, macros, autohotkey, shortcut

i am trying to execute scripts by using shortcuts but cant do it. When i press shift, code is not waiting for other key and executing first condition. Can you help?

my code looks like that:

```
x := 500
~Shift::
sleep, 500
loop,
{
if GetKeyState("S","p")
    {
    Send, {BS}
    Sleep, 200 ; for buffer (1000 = 1second)
    Send, 600.01.02.02
    Send, {Ctrl Down}
    Send, {Enter}
    Send, {Ctrl Up}
    Return
 }
if GetKeyState("M","p")
    {
    Send, {BS}
    Sleep, 200 ; for buffer (1000 = 1second)
    Send, 600.01.05.02
    Send, {Ctrl Down}
    Send, {Enter}
    Send, {Ctrl Up}
    Return
 }
}
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you need it to work one way is to use a `keywait, shift` right below the hotkey

You can also use multible hotkeys under one another to do it

```
~+s::
~+p::
Sleep 500
Loop
{
```

There are other ways but both of those will work